# How to get substring without cutting words in between in Java?

Tags: java, android

I have so many strings and i want to print them all one by one. problem is, i have limited width to print the string. so is there any way to know when the width ends and remaining string should come in next line. and words should not be cut.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called word wrapping. Search for "word wrap java" and you'll find some examples, like [this one](http://ramblingsrobert.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/java-word-wrap-algorithm/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [StaticLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/StaticLayout.html) to lay out your text into multiple lines that fit within a given width.